# Finding the span and basis of V.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Let $V =\{(x, y, z, w)|x=y+z, w=2y\}$ be a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^4$.
>
> (i) Write down an explicit form of a general vector of $V$.
>
> (ii) Express $V$ in linear span form.
>
> (iii) Write down a basis for $V$ and find $\dim V$.

To answer (i), I managed to get $\Big\{l(1,0,1,0) + t(1/2,1/2,0,1)|t, l \in \Bbb{R}\Big\}$. Which brings me to the next part (ii) and (iii), is it right to say that both the basis and span of $V$ is

$V= \{(1,0,1,0),(1/2,1/2,0,1)\}$?

Comment: The span is not the basis, but all linear combinations of the basis (sums of constant times basis element).

Comment: $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ is a *basis* of $\Bbb{R}^2$ but the span of these vectors is entire $\Bbb{R}^2$. So basis and span are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=t,z=s$, then we can then deduce that vectors in $V$ are of this form: $$\Big\{(t+s,t,s,2t)=t(1,1,0,2)+s(1,0,1,0)\;:\;s,t\in \mathbb{R}\Big\}$$ From that the two vectors $(1,1,0,2),(1,0,1,0)$ are linearly independent and form a basis for $V$. So dimension of $V$ is $2$.

Comment: I would replace the "we can see" part by "since the two vectors are linearly independent, they form a basis of V".

Comment: yes, I edited it!